# DDE INITIATE failed. (3153)

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

Progress ABL    : OpenEdge Release 11.6
Operation System: Windows 7
Microsoft Office: 2013
Description:
That is a Reporting Project. The Progress 4GL is used by report generation with the Office Word. And the DDE initiate is failed. I don't known what is the happen.
I reference the Progress Document, which said same the problem is solved by  OpenEdge Release 11.5.1. But I don't think so. Now I hope every body give the help. Thanks

[DDE INITIATE failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhJZS.png)
[DDE TESTING code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cI0jK.png)

Issue Coding:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE ddeid AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE frame-handle AS HANDLE NO-UNDO.

CREATE FRAME frame-handle
ASSIGN visible = TRUE
       hidden  = TRUE.
       
DDE INITIATE ddeid FRAME frame-handle
APPLICATION "Excel" TOPIC "System".
```

Comment: Why don't you use COM-HANDLE? It's much easier than DDE and faster in most cases.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason and solved

1. Missing the winword.exe path
2. Missing WinExec Procedure

Coding:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE ddeid AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE frame-handle AS HANDLE NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE return-code AS INT  NO-UNDO.

CREATE FRAME frame-handle
ASSIGN visible = TRUE
       hidden  = TRUE.

PROCEDURE WinExec EXTERNAL "KERNEL32.DLL":
    DEFINE INPUT PARAMETER ProgramName AS CHARACTER.
    DEFINE INPUT PARAMETER VisualStyle AS LONG.
    DEFINE RETURN PARAMETER StatusCode AS LONG.
END PROCEDURE.

RUN WinExec(INPUT "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\winword.exe", INPUT 1, OUTPUT return-code).
DDE INITIATE ddeid FRAME frame-handle
APPLICATION "Winword" TOPIC "System".
```